# Can you upload files to CloudControl via SSH or FTP?

Tags: php, git, yii, cloudcontrol

I am new to CloudControl and to git, though I have been programming for a while.

I am just testing CC and setup a test php app, and am using Yii (which I already know). I have the app created, along with a "testing" branch all following this guide: https://www.cloudcontrol.com/dev-center/Guides/PHP/Yii%201.1.10

I do NOT have the "framework" directory inside my Yii apps directory. It is one directory higher, and is recommended that way by Yii (so it is not in the web root). It would make sense to also not have this framework directory under git, which is why the folder is also not deployed to my cloudcontrol app.

So my question is, can I FTP or SSH to my CloudControl app to upload this folder manually (so my app can actually run on CC), or do I need to move the folder into my app's directory, put it under git, and deploy it to CC? It can not run at the moment because the Yii framework folder does not exist on my CloudControl app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, we do not offer SSH or FTP upload because all dependencies have to be part of the image that is built during a Git push. They are not however required to be in the repository. It is actually recommended to use composer to track your dependencies for PHP. I see Yii now supports this, so the guide on our site seems a little outdated by now.

THe PHP Buildpack does support Yii and takes care of setting the webroot. You can have a look here: https://github.com/cloudControl/buildpack-php It also offers to have custom Apache or PHP configurations if you require a different configuration.